# How to update a column with sequential numbers using cursor in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Expected result is

```
code    descd   slnum
======================
10       a       1
11       b       2
12       c       3
```

I have tried like this but I'm missing somewhere

```
DECLARE @DF TABLE(code int, descd varchar(7), slnum int)

INSERT INTO @DF VALUES(10, 'a', 0), (11, 'b', 0), (12, 'c', 0)

DECLARE @s as INT = 0
DECLARE @code as INT = 0

DECLARE scursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT code, slnum 
    FROM @DF 
    FOR UPDATE of slnum

OPEN scursor

FETCH NEXT FROM scursor INTO @code, @s

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE @DF
    SET @s = slnum = @s + 1 
    WHERE current of scursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM scursor INTO @code, @s
END

CLOSE scursor
DEALLOCATE scursor
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do. Update the question with expected result. I am sure this does not require *CURSOR*

Answer (score 1):

One simple, **set-based** statement will do - no messy and clunky cursor needed!!

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        code,
        SeqNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code)
    FROM
        @DF
)
UPDATE d
SET slnum = SeqNum
FROM @DF d
INNER JOIN CTE ON d.Code = CTE.code
```

Now when you look at your table:

```
SELECT * FROM @DF
```

you should get this output:

[image]

which is what you were trying to get - correct?

Comment: But i wanna use cursor compulsorily its a homework. I'm missing in that process

Answer (score 1):

You can `without any order` as the below:

```
DECLARE @SeqNum INT = 0

UPDATE  @DF
SET slnum = @SeqNum,
    @SeqNum += 1
```

Result:

```
code        descd   slnum
----------- ------- -----------
10          a       1
11          b       2
12          c       3
```

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE @ttb table  (code VARCHAR(5), descd VARCHAR(5), slnum int)
INSERT INTO @ttb VALUES(10,'a',0),(11,'b',0),(12,'c',0)
DECLARE @s INT=1
DECLARE @value INT

DECLARE scursor  CURSOR FOR

SELECT slnum
FROM @ttb
for update of slnum

OPEN scursor

FETCH NEXT FROM scursor
INTO @value

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
update @ttb
set slnum=@s
where current of scursor
select @s=@s+1
FETCH NEXT FROM scursor INTO @value
END

CLOSE scursor
DEALLOCATE scursor
select * from @ttb